# jQuery select all children of closest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the `.red-border` class to a `#container` div and all `<td>`s in the closest `<tr>`.

But by using .closest() I only get the elements immediate parent `<td>`.

Is there a way I can target all children of the closest `<tr>`?

My code is below.

My current erroneous JS:

```
$('#myelement').closest('.container, tr td').addClass('red-border');
```

Obviously, this only targets 1 `td`. I want to encompass all of them.

My HTML:

```
<div id="container">
 <span class="myelement">element</span>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="myelement">element</span></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: normally I might use the `.find()` function but this wouldnt work with the `or` operator.

Comment: the closest `tr` to `myelement` is the first `tr`, so why not use `tr:first` or `$("#myelement").parent().siblings("table").find("tr").eq(0)`?

Comment: I can target the `tr` fine, but I want to target that `tr`s child `td`s. Also, just tagetting the `tr` would break my or operator.

Comment: can you show sample of the code after change??

Comment: hey try putting some text in empty td ,you will get solution

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6gpz9gzq/) check this demo it is not one line though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are expecting. You need to iterate through each `tr` and add `red-border` class to its first `td` with `td:first` selector as below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container').addClass('red-border');
  $('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td:first').addClass('red-border');
  })
})
```

```css
.red-border{
  border:red 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span class="myelement">element</span>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First row First TD</td>
    <td><span class="myelement">element</span>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second row First TD</td>
    <td><span class="myelement">element</span>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i think what he means is all td of the closest tr to container so we can that it is the first tr of the next table.

Comment: @guradio I don't think that's what he meant. He said _I want to add the .red-border class to a #container div and all <td>s in the closest <tr>._ i.e. to the #container and all `td's` which is closest to their `tr`which means first `td` of every `tr`.

Comment: `all <td>s in the closest <tr>` if i understand this closest TR is first tr of next table then all td in that tr just my understanding. OP should clarify it if it causes confusion :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao shouldn't that be *all closest <td>s in all <tr>s*?

Comment: Agreed @guradio.. Not sure what OP meant to achieve with his question.

Comment: @Developer107.. Which one? I did not get what you asked.. This solutions targets all closest `td` to the `tr` i.e. first `td` of every `tr`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao sorry for being unclear but what I meant was *i.e. to the #container and all td's which is closest to their trwhich means first td of every tr*- Doesn't this mean when OP adds `all closest <td>s in all <tr>s` in question? Here OP has added `all <td>s in the closest <tr>`.

Comment: @Developer107.. OP has just given an example of what he requires if am not wrong. I believe there will  be multiple `tr td` and he wants to add that `class` to first `td` of each `tr`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao The question has lead to different perspectives in understanding it :) It would be helpful if OP clears the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

According to your structure you can go for this:

```
$(".myelement").parents("#container").addClass('red-border').siblings("table").find("tr").eq(0).children().addClass('red-border');
```

target the parent `#container` using `parents()`. This will give nothing for the `span` inside `td`. Then target its sibling `table` and the first `tr` by using `eq(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

why do you want it in a single line? just split it to two, it will be simpler.

```
$('.myelement').closest('#container').addClass('red-border');
$('.myelement').closest('tr').find('td').addClass('red-border');
```

by the way, you called `#myelement` when your tag had a class `myelement`. It should be called using `.myelement`. And the container is an id so `#container`

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo! To answer your question, it's because I need an 'or' operator in there.

Answer (score 1):

Call class element using **.myelement** instead of **#myelement**

```
$('.myelement').closest('.container, tr td').css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```

or

```
$('.myelement').closest('.container, tr td').addClass('red-border');
```